# PHP - How to remove pagination page variable from URL?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am tryign to remove pagination page ID from URL. For example I have URL looks like this:

```
$urlVal = "http://192.168.1.233/sitename/property-list?page=13&page=11&sproperty=for sale&srooms=1,10&scity=&scountry=&lat=31.0000000&long=35.0000000&sprice=100,100000";
```

And want to remove, If any of matches match from URL:

```
1. page=1
2. page=1&page=2
3. page=1&page=2$page=3
4. page=1&page=2$page=3$page=4
```

In my current pagination code, Previous page is concating everytime when page is changed thats why I want to remove all page.

I have used this code but not working well.

```
$urlVal = "http://192.168.1.233/sitename/property-list?page=13&page=11&sproperty=for sale&srooms=1,10&scity=&scountry=&lat=31.0000000&long=35.0000000&sprice=100,100000";

//$getUrl =$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$parts = parse_url($urlVal);
$urlVar = "";                   
$urlVar = $parts['query'];
echo $urlVar = preg_replace('/page=[0-9]&+/', '', $urlVar);
```

Try my code here: http://codepad.org/lSHV7a7w

I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$urlVal = "http://192.168.1.233/sitename/property-list?page=13&page=11&sproperty=for sale&srooms=1,10&scity=&scountry=&lat=31.0000000&long=35.0000000&sprice=100,100000";

$parts = parse_url($urlVal);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
unset($query['page']);
$newUrl = "{$parts['scheme']}://{$parts['host']}{$parts['path']}?" . http_build_query($query);

echo $newUrl;

// Regx Pattern
echo preg_replace('/&?page=[0-9]+&?/', '', $parts['query']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using concatenation of numbers as page value?

```
$urlVal = "http://192.168.1.233/sitename/property-list?page=11,13&etc..."
```

It shortens url and makes removing parameter easy:

```
$urlVar = preg_replace('/page=[0-9,]+&/', '', $urlVar);
```

You can extract them from url using:

```
preg_match("/page=([0-9,]+)&/", $urlVal, $m);
$pages = explode(",", $m[1]);
```